# Reactive Microservices Example - Generic & REAL (Not Abstract)

Tags: microservices

Every business is in the process of finding customers, making products, selling them to customers, etc.

I've been to a lecture on reactive microservices and know what they are in abstract form, but NOBODY (and I mean NOBODY) seems to be able to give me a good real life example in regards to how the software being created today would be better designed by utilizing reactive microservices.

For example, a webservice that does Thing1 for a customer.  It has three major components, SubThing1, SubThing2, SubThing3.  SubThing2 can be much more memory and resource intensive at times, so it would be good to break it into reactive microservices so that SubThing2 can be scaled up and down when needed.

Can You give me a real time live working practical example of Thing1, SubThing1, SubThing2, and SubThing3.

Comment: I've done a lot microservice solutions before, however the term "reactive" is a new association to microservice to me, could you share your source on what is a "reactive microservice"?

Comment: @Bishoy - definition in my answer below....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kind of chain of actions you can encounter. A message is emitted each time an action is completed.

```
Process an order from a client
  => Update stock
    => Restock
  => Update client fidelity points
    => Send a gift
```

A first service processes an order and emits a message.

This message triggers an agent that updates the stock. Updating the stock emits a message. This message triggers an agent that checks that no stock falls under a given minimum. If the stock reaches the minimum, then the agent order more items from the supplier.

The first message algo triggers an agent that computes the fidelity points of the clients. Updating the fidelity points emits a message. This message triggers an agent that gives a gift to client that reaches a given thresold.